# Add Query parameter in Mule HTTP Outbound endpoint

Tags: mule

How to add Query parameter in mule HTTP Outbound Endpoint.
Without passing in path.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you need to send the following url to Outbound endpoint which contains the following :- **Query Parameter** :-

```
http://localhost:8083/mule/?Item1=abc&Item2=efg
```

So,now as you said you don't need to pass the **Query Parameter** in url..

So in that case you can do the following :-

You can set the **Query Parameter** in Outbound Property using set-property just before the Outbound Endpoint as follow :-

```
<set-property propertyName="Item1" value="abc" doc:name="Property"/>
<set-property propertyName="Item2" value="efg" doc:name="Property"/>
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://localhost:8083/mule/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

And you can simply pass `http://localhost:8083/mule/` in Outbound endpoint address  and the **Query Parameter** will be passed to external flow as an Outbound properties with message payload

**Note**: This is only incase of **old** HTTP outbound endpoint (Mule 3.5 or older), where query param are treated as outbbond properties

Comment: This seems to set a header, not a query parameter.

Comment: The outbound http endpoint sends the query parameters as properties ...this is old http endpoint used in Mule 3.5 and below and you will get query parameters as message properties

Answer (score 0):

You can add the parameters in the outbound connector itself. you have the option to pass the hard coded data as well as MEL expressions are also allowed.

```
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/post" method="POST" doc:name="outbound">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="q1" value="#[payload.input1]"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
```

Comment: http:request is the 3.6 stuff right? is there way to do so in version such as 3.5.x ?